# Basic scheduling algortihms (FCFS, RR, SPN, HRRN, Feedback)?

Tags: algorithm, process, scheduling

I need help understanding the basic scheduling algorithms: FCFS, Round Robin(q=1), Round Robin (q=4), SPN shortest process next, Highest response ratio next (HRRN), feedback (q=1), feedback (q=2^i).

Comment: Isn't the Banker's algorithm one implementation of a deadlock avoidance algorithm?

Comment: seems to belong more on programmers.stackexchange